# Using AJAX with Laravel GET request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

What I am trying to do is to load `@yield('somecontent.content')` on a master a master layout dynamically. Just for informative purposes I have the following:

**Controller**:

```
public function someFunction()
{
    //DB logic here
    return view('/exampleView')
    ->with($dataset1)
    ->with($dataset2)
    ->with($dataset3)
    ->with($dataset4);
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('someRoute', ['as' => 'theRoute', 'uses' => 'someController@someFunction']);
```

**Ajax/jquery function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ajaxClick').click(function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'theRoute',
       datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       console.log('AJAX loaded something');
    }, 
    error: function(){
       console.log('AJAX load did not work');
    }
    });
 });
});
```

**View logic:**

```
<a class="ajaxClick" data-name="{{ 
route('theRoute') }}" href="#">Testing Ajax</a>
```

In the a tag I had the route originally which would work but would refresh the page and not load without refreshing.

How it flows is, click the link in the navbar and load the Laravel route dynamically in a set field which is allocated for views to load in by using `@yield('somecontent')`.

Also another question would be, how would you implement this in Laravel? If need anything else comment.

Thankyou!

**P.S**
This [example](http://akveo.com/blur-admin-mint/#/charts/chartist) of a dashboard is pretty much what I want to do, how the content loads straight away without any refreshing of the page.

Comment: What does your browser console say? Also check the _Network_ tab. FYI, it's `dataType`, not `datatype` (case is important). Also, the error callback has information passed to it which you can use. For example ~ `error: (jqXhr, status, error) => { console.error(status, error) }`

Comment: Another issue, your response must be JSON. Otherwise it will fail.

Comment: @itachi actually, with the incorrect `datatype`, it won't matter 

Comment: yeah. Agreed. It shouldn't matter as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you still want to use jQuery, you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajaxClick').click(function(event){
        //event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'theRoute',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#main-wrapper').html(data);
            }, 
            error: function(){
                console.log('AJAX load did not work');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I suggest you try and study javascript frameworks. The link you sent is using Angular JS, and the functionalities you need are built into them, and is called SPA or Single Page Application

Uncomplete list of JS Framework:

- Angular
- React
- Vue